# Configure Entity Framework v6 Code-First Identifiers to use ALL CAPS

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like Entity Framework v6 to not use quotes around identifiers when executing transactions against the database.  Is it possible to configure the DbContext to do this without creating a configuration file for every entity?

For example:

Instead of

```
SELECT "ApplicationId"
FROM "dbo"."Applications";
```

I want

```
SELECT ApplicationId
FROM dbo.Applications;
```

Will Entity Framework be able to correctly map properties and entities to the database fields and tables correctly?

EDIT:

Rather than try to eliminate the quotation marks, I should have indicated that my goal is to interface with an Oracle DB.  Oracle will require using quotation marks around identifiers that contain lowercase letters.  So, I should probably change my request to indicate that I need all uppercase identifiers.

I came up with part of a solution in the OnModelCreating method of the DbContext, but it won't handle Foreign Key identifiers:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Properties()
           .Configure(c => c.HasColumnName(c.ClrPropertyInfo.Name.ToUpperInvariant()));
        modelBuilder.Types()
           .Configure(c => c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name.ToUpperInvariant()));            
    }
```

Comment: I believe it's not possible... or at least there's not a straightforward approach to accomplish this. Why you want this? Your question doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @FabioLuz I restated my requirements with a partial solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the foreign key properties in your class, and then map their database column. Like this [How to configure DbContext to work with Oracle ODP.Net and EF CodeFirst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729750/how-to-configure-dbcontext-to-work-with-oracle-odp-net-and-ef-codefirst)

Or, if you don't want to put the foreign key property in the classes, you should use the fluent API to map the foreign key using uppercase letters. Like this example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>() 
    .HasRequired(c => c.Department) 
    .WithMany(t => t.Courses) 
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("CHANGEDDEPARTMENTID"));
```