# How to use ef6.0 to migrate the database to Oracle database fields that are generated in Upper

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, dbmigrate

I used ef6.0 to migrate the database to Oracle, how to build a database field in Upper

Comment: I used entity-framework-6 code-first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the other question:  [Configure Entity Framework v6 Code-First Identifiers to use ALL CAPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297341/configure-entity-framework-v6-code-first-identifiers-to-use-all-caps)  and I find the answer ,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Properties()
       .Configure(c => c.HasColumnName(c.ClrPropertyInfo.Name.ToUpperInvariant()));
    modelBuilder.Types()
       .Configure(c => c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name.ToUpperInvariant()));            
}
```

I wish could help other people in need.