# C# Entity Framework Core - wrong .ToList() "autoselect" to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

From my app I have opened a connection to Oracle with a `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` and used it for Entity Framework Core in this code:

```
optionsBuilder.UseOracle(connection)
```

My issue its when I call something like this:

```
txtStop_Trading_Message.Text = context.GlobalParam.ToList().First().Stop_Trading_Message;
```

I get an error:

> Failed executing DbCommand (51ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
>   SELECT "g"."ID", "g"."DChange", "g"."Deleted", "g"."Is_Stop_Trading", "g"."Stop_Trading_Message", "g"."Uzi_ID"
>   FROM "PROSTREAM"."Global_param" "g"
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

But this code is working correctly:

```
txtStop_Trading_Message.Text = context.GlobalParam.FromSql("SELECT * FROM PROSTREAM.Global_param g FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY").ToList().First().Stop_Trading_Message;
```

So EF "autoselect" of the `.ToList()` function does not work, because in select its `"` char, any idea why?

When I take this select and remove the chars `"`, select is ok and working with `.FromSql()` function, also in SQL Developer, etc...

Thanks you...

Comment: Resolved by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729750/how-to-configure-dbcontext-to-work-with-oracle-odp-net-and-ef-codefirst